# My PHP installation not support PostgreSQL

Tags: ubuntu

when i try localhost/pgadmin, show this message:

> Your PHP installation does not support PostgreSQL. You need to
>   recompile PHP using the --with-pgsql configure option.

nothing works :x

i use ubuntu 12.04

Comment: have you install `php5-pgsql` ?

Comment: yes! but not working.

Comment: what do you get in your `phpinfo();` check if the module is loaded or not ?

Comment: in my phpinfo() not appear postgresql information.